# Checking for 2 consecutive string of numbers of a zipcode

Tags: php, regex, function, math, logic

I want to check a string eg. 56401 which has 2 consecutive numbers (5,6) and check reverse too (6,5) and needs to return false else true.I tried to use preg_match but I do not think it is working properly:

```
/\d{4}/
```

Any idea on how to improve this?

Comment: Regular expressions are a great tool, but they can't solve every problem. In this case, I would definitely not use them. Parse the number out into digits then check the difference between each consecutive pair.

Comment: Or just substring the first 2 numbers, do it again and flip them, then check that way

Comment: Are you perhaps trying to identify palindromes?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use regular expressions, I'd recommend something like this:

```
function has_consecutive_chars($input) {
    $chars = str_split($input);
    for ($i = 1; $i < count($chars); $i++)
    {
        if (abs($chars[$i] - $chars[$i-1]) == 1)
        {
           return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

has_consecutive_chars('56401'); // true
has_consecutive_chars('72674'); // true
has_consecutive_chars('53794'); // false
```

Notice, this will also work with non-numbers (e.g. `'ab'` will be counted as a consecutive pair). If you only want this function to work with numbers, I recommend you validate your string before passing it into this function (regular expressions are a good solution for that).

Comment: this looks good however it seems that it only works on the first 2 numbers, not for example say: 72674 (6,7 being consecutive)

Comment: @GSZingh It works for me, but perhaps you had put an `else` after the `if` or grouped the second `return` under the `for`, either of which would cause that behavior. I've updated the answer for clarity.